# how to select multiple blocks from multiple files by python?

Tags: python, text

I would like to select multiple blocks (parts) from a file and from all of these similar files.
The file below is an example download from internet.

'session_start' and 'session_end' will mark the block/part which I want to take out. There are two blocks in below example. In real case, there will be many blocks marked with 'session_start' and 'session_end'. The number of blocks is not the same on these files.
Can I ask how to do it in Python?

'**session_start**'In today's Internet, the path from a source to a destination may
be different than the path from the destination back to the source
("asymmetric paths"), such that different sequences of routers are
used for the forward and reverse paths.'**session_end**'
Therefore, round-trip measurements actually measure the performance of two distinct
paths together. Measuring each path independently highlights the
'**session_start**'performance difference between the two paths that may traverse
different Internet service providers and even radically different
types of networks (for example, research versus commodity
networks, or networks with'**session_end**' asymmetric link capacities, or wireless
versus wireline access).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```py
text = """
'session_start'In today's Internet, the path from a source to a destination may be different than the path from the destination back to the source ("asymmetric paths"), such that different sequences of routers are used for the forward and reverse paths.'session_end' Therefore, round-trip measurements actually measure the performance of two distinct paths together. Measuring each path independently highlights the 'session_start'performance difference between the two paths that may traverse different Internet service providers and even radically different types of networks (for example, research versus commodity networks, or networks with'session_end' asymmetric link capacities, or wireless versus wireline access).
"""

start_index = 0
START = "'session_start'"
END = "'session_end'"
while True:
    start_index = text.find(START, start_index)
    if start_index < 0:
        break
    start_index += len(START)
    end = text.find(END, start_index)
    block = text[start_index : end]
    print(block)
    print()
    start_index = end + len(END)
```

Output

```
In today's Internet, the path from a source to a destination may be different than the path from the destination back to the source ("asymmetric paths"), such that different sequences of routers are used for the forward and reverse paths.

performance difference between the two paths that may traverse different Internet service providers and even radically different types of networks (for example, research versus commodity networks, or networks with
```